# Pandas: convert to numeric with callback

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm converting columns & cell values of a dataframe to float64 using either:

```
df.infer_objects()
```

or

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

The first keeps those columns as object-type that are not convertible while the second one raises an exception if some objects are can not be converted. My question is, if it's somehow possible to supply my own error/converter callback function? Something like this:

```
def my_converter(value: object) -> float:
  # add all your "known" value conversions and fallbacks
  converted_value = float(value)
  return converted_value

df.apply(pd.to_numeric, converter=my_converted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to concisely do exactly what your asking. That would be a nice addition to the api though. Here is something that will work, it's a little convoluted.

Set the `pd.to_numeric` method to not raise an exception but instead return a NaN using the `errors` parameter. Using the location of your NaN `apply` your special converter function. Now use `add` and the paramter `fill_value=0` to add the DataFrames that were converted with `pd.to_numeric` and with your special converter.

You can find some information in the docs for [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)

It would look something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': np.random.randn(5),
                    'B': np.random.randn(5)})

    A           B
0   -0.619165   1.310489
1   0.908564    1.017284
2   0.046072    -1.059349
3   1.123730    -2.229261
4   0.689580    -0.200981

df1 = df[df < 1] # This is your DataFrame from df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df1

    A           B
0   -0.619165   NaN
1   0.908564    NaN
2   0.046072    -1.059349
3   NaN         -2.229261
4   0.689580    -0.200981

df2 = df[df1.isnull()] 
df2 # This is the DataFrame you want to apply your converter df2.apply(my_converter)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x*10) # This is my dummy special converter
df2

    A           B
0   NaN         13.104885
1   NaN         10.172835
2   NaN         NaN
3   11.237296   NaN
4   NaN         NaN

df1.add(df2, fill_value=0) # This is the final dataframe you're looking for

    A           B
0   -0.619165   13.104885
1   0.908564    10.172835
2   0.046072    -1.059349
3   11.237296   -2.229261
4   0.689580    -0.200981
```

Comment: Yeah, after what I figured out during the day, this is more or less the way to go.